# Lost connection to “iPhone”. in x-code 9.1 and iOS 11.1.1 app close

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9.1

In my app project when i traverse through 2-3 screen, x-code automatically release connection to phone, and app minimize like crash, but when i see in firebase there is no crash log. so I think it is ios11 problem and because app crashes for no reason without doing any heavy task. Memory usage is 55 MB when app crashes. Any solution will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Xcode 9.1 and reset the all device connection. it is working.

Comment: how we tell client, restart device when crash happen ?